# I am getting a connection error while setting up DB2-s5 on IBM Cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I've been trying to set up the Lite Plan - DB2-s5 on IBM Cloud and it gives me an Connection Error all the time.

Please, help would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn how to ask a good question!   Never write "it gives me an connection error", but instead write the exact connection error message in plain text and show exactly how you try to connect  (not graphic picture).  When you get the error message, google the error code number.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:
The Service "Db2-1q" has not been created due to a network error. Please try again at a later time. [...]

There is no error number, so I can't find any solution online either. I guess this is a general problem with IBM cloud right now, maybe it will be fixed some time soon.